# Firefox - postiton sticky turns off when scroll-behaviour smooth is on

Tags: html, css, firefox, sticky, smooth-scrolling

I am working on a onepage website. I am trying to make sticky navigation bar that uses id anchors. Everything was working fine until I introduced smooth scrolling.

I placed scroll-behaviour:smooth on html selector and it crashed sticky behaviour on Firefox 65.0.1. It works properly on Chrome. To picture the problem I've created this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/bkudyba/pen/VRZmMO). To regenerate the problem, open it in Firefox and try commenting out the scroll-behaviour property.

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

I am aware that I could redo this with JS, but I am aiming for lightweight page so I would like to do it natively. I am also aware that I can redo this with position fixed, yet I wonder if I used something in a wrong manner or it is a Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use an interesting trick, i make body as a flex container, and it has 2 containers: nav and wrapper, so it looks like the page is scrolling but actually the wrapper is scrolling which makes effect that nav is stick to the top:

(and yeah, `postition:sticky;` has very poor support, so I don't recommend to use it)

```css
body
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap
{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

*
{
margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  blahblahblah
  <a href="#title1">sdf</a>
</nav>
<div class="wrap">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta 
  <h1 id="title1">
    hi
  </h1>
  laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic obcaecati alias facere, illo voluptas incidunt impedit eos tenetur, earum perspiciatis enim soluta laudantium, repellat ad autem commodi provident qui possimus.
</div>
```